# How to eliminate the decimal point in the product price and add zeros based on the number of digits post period operator?

Tags: magento2.3, php, javascript

I need to ensure the product price either gets 0 appended to it with decimal point removed if there is only one digit after the decimal point or 00 appended if there is no decimal point. The logic I could come up with so far is as follows. I would request SO to enlighten me on making this work with your correction. Thanks

Suppose the product price is 458.99
  I need it to be 45899- only remove the period.
Suppose the product price is 458.9
  I need it to be 45890
Suppose the product price is 458
  I need it to be 45800

```
$str=$_product->getFinalPrice(); 
if (!is_int($str) {
    if (strpos($str, '.') === false )) {
        $new_str = $val . 00;   
    } elseif (strlen(substr(strrchr($str, "."), 1)) == 1{
        $new_str = str_replace('.','', $str) . 0; 
    } elseif (strlen(substr(strrchr($str, "."), 1)) == 2 {
        $new_str = str_replace('.','', $str);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code. I have checked and it worked as per your requirement.

```
$price = 458.99; 
// $price = 458.9; 
// $price = 458; 

if (!is_int($price)) {
    if (strpos($price, '.') === false ) {
    $newPrice = $price . '00';   
    } 
    else if (strlen(substr(strrchr($price, "."), 1)) == 1 ){
        $newPrice = str_replace('.','', $price) . 0; 
    } 
    else if (strlen(substr(strrchr($price, "."), 1)) == 2 ){
        $newPrice = str_replace('.','', $price);
    }
} else {    
    $newPrice = $price . '00';
}

echo $newPrice; // return 45899
```

Please accept as an answer if work for you.

Comment: thanks. I arrived at the same logic a little while ago except for the the last else block which is too important.